# Unable to load custom plugin in NSIS script

Tags: nsis

I have a made custom NSIS plugin to perform certain operations. 
In the NSIS script, I have loaded the plugin through following command:

```
!addplugindir "Plugin\"
```

(in the same folder where this nsis script is present, there is a folder called "Plugin" in which dll named *ExDll.dll* is present)

and I am executing the functions of DLL through following command:

```
ExDll::Func123 "<param1>" "<param2>"
```

After compilation, the executable is properly executed with no issues. But when I move the same executable to another system, I get the following error:

```
Could not load: C:\Users\user123\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw19B5.tmp\ExDll.dll
```

I checked the above directory ("C:\Users\user123\AppData\Local\Temp\nsw19B5.tmp"), DLL "*ExDll.dll*" is present there.

So, I have following queries:

1. What can be the possible reason behind this?
2. **How shall I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some dependencies. Inspect your .DLL with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the problematic system. You will most likely find that you are linking directly to one of the [MSVCRT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=VS.100).aspx) files and the VC C++ runtime files are not installed on said systems.

You could change your code so you [don't need the CRT](https://www.catch22.net/tuts/reducing-executable-size) ([/Zl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1tbxcxh.aspx)) or switch to static linking ([/MT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)).